# Is it ok to put Bootstraps' col-*-* class on input elements?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a responsive form using Bootstrap. Is it correct to use col-**-* classes like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <input class="col-*-blabla" ... ... >
    <input class="col-*-blabla" ... ... >
</div>
```

or should I nest them inside of a div with the col class like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-*-*">
     <input .. ... >
   </div>
   <div class="col-*-*">
     <input .. ... >
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should nest them. There is one example in Bootstrap documentation that shows use of `col-` classes on label elements ([Horizontal forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)).

Look at this example, red block is a div with default `col-xs-12` class inside `row`, as you can see below this container, when you use `col-` classes on input elements they will be misaligned (that's because it applies padding to input elements itself).

```css
.div {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="div"></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" class="col-xs-4">
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    
</div>
```